# Sending a mail results in "Bad ENVID parameter syntax"

Tags: email, email-client

I like to send a mail, but Thunderbird is aborting it with showing "Bad ENVID parameter syntax".

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to disable DSN (Delivery Status Notification).

See ENVID parameter in the RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3885